# deserialize mongodb datetime field "$time" of JSON document field in C#/SSIS Script component

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, ssis, script-component

I am trying to deserialize a mongodb's datetime "$time" field from a JSON file in Script Component SSIS/C# WITHOUT using newtonsoft. This is how far I have reached. Thanks for any help.

Example of my JSON file:

[
{
"studentId":A2336,
"LastUpdatedDateTime":{ "$date":"2022-08-12T20:11:30.324Z"}} ,
{
"studentId":B1470,
"LastUpdatedDateTime":{ "$date":"2021-03-02T21:22:44.310Z"}
}
]

```
//current code
Public overridevoidCreateNewOutputRows(){
      String jsonFileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\desktop\sample.json");
      javaScriptSerializer js = newjavaScriptSerializer();
      List<Student> allStudents = js.Deserialize<List<Student>>(jsonFileContent);
foreach(var student inallStudents)
          {
               Output0Buffer.AddRow();
               System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Student Id is: "+ student.studentId.ToString());
               Output0Buffer.StudentId = student.studentId;
        
               //how to print/convert the LastUpdatedDateTime to the datetime Output0Buffer field?
              //this gives and error that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
               System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Student Id is: "+ student.LastUpdatedDateTime.date.ToString());
//this yields in "Student Id is: "
               System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Student Id is: "+ student.LastUpdatedDateTime.date);

             //here I am trying to assign it to an ouput0buffer field
                  Output0Buffer.LastUpdatedDateTime = student.LastUpdatedDateTime.date;

    }
}


Class Student
{
    Public String studentId { get; set;}
    Public Jsondatetime LastUpdatedDateTime  {get; set;}
}

Class Jsondatetime
{
    Public String date { get; set;}
}
```

I have tried creating a different class for the "$date" like shown in the code above. It yeilds to and error  when trying to print as a string and yeilds as a blank when trying to print as is. I expected the exact value of the key "$date".

Comment: Please fix the code in your question. You have keywords using incorrect casing and running together with no white space and it's not clear what the capitalization should be in some cases. Also use proper white space formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is not valid, you have to fix it by adding " to studentId. Since you are using an ancient deserializer, try this code

```
var jsonFileContent = "[ { \"studentId\":\"A2336\", \"LastUpdatedDateTime\":{ \"$date\":\"2022-08-12T20:11:30.324Z\"}} , { \"studentId\":\"B1470\", \"LastUpdatedDateTime\":{ \"$date\":\"2021-03-02T21:22:44.310Z\"} } ]";

jsonFileContent = jsonFileContent.Replace("\"$date\"", "\"date\"");

 List<Student> allStudents = js.Deserialize<List<Student>>(jsonFileContent);

DateTime date = allStudents[0].LastUpdatedDateTime.date;


public class Student
{
    public string studentId { get; set; }
    public LastUpdatedDateTime LastUpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
}
public class LastUpdatedDateTime
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```